# What is the procedure to get the prediction in real-time after long running off-line Spark (MLlib) model training?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

For example, if I use MLlib logistic regression to train data set, and each of the data has over 100,000,000 features, after hours of training we get the model, how to use the model to predict in “real-time” so, for example, a web page responses to user with the prediction result in 200ms?
Simply use `model.predict(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Spark 2.0  Logistic Regression only supports **binary classification** .  The OP said regression.. so we will need to follow up on that..

In any case for Binary Classification using Logistic Regressiob the work done for *prediction* is almost trivial:

```
BLAS.dot(features, coefficients) + intercept
```

So Spark simply needs to take the DOT product of the trained weights ("coefficients") and the input row.

One thing to keep in mind: a single row **must fit into memory on a single machine**.  In addition the number of elements in the vector== number of features must be kept <= 2^31.

**Further update**  `Regression` in Spark 2.0 MLlib is handled through the `GeneralizedLinearRegression` class that supports the following "families":

- Gaussian
- Binomial
- Poisson
- Gamma

The computation is carried out by `WeightedLeastSquares` similarly to the `LogisticRegression`

```
BLAS.dot(features, coefficients) + intercept
```

So the complexity is **low** for prediction - so a prediction should finish **about as quickly as it takes to load the observation to be predicted into Spark** , and irrespective of its size. It just needs to fit into memory of one machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however what I don't know is if we have the trained model already, and the features are huge, how do we "calculate the prediction in real-time"? If the `predict` method is slow due to any reason, such as very high dimension features, any way to make it in real-time?

Comment: @Stephen  Ah yea.. I had not payed close enough attention. "100Meg features".  That's a lot.   I'm going to look at the source code to see what that would actually mean in real life.

Comment: @Stephen   Updated the answer.  A key consideration specifically for LogReg in Spark2.0 is it only supports Binary Classification.  From your OP it was Regression: so lemme know if you had a particular (different) regression algorithm in mind.  I have updated the answer also to make some suggestions here.

Comment: Yes, I mean classification.

Comment: @Stephen  As mentioned the LogisticRegression in MLlib is actually Binary Classification.  The answer for that is already shown in the first part of the revised answer.     Or were you instead needing multinomial? Your OP did not specify this information.

Comment: I would like to ask one more question. If I call the `predict` method on model, ex: on `LogisticRegressionModel`, there are 3 `predict` methods in it. One of them is `predict(testData: Vector): Double`, does it mean I can add the spark jar in my classpath and then I call `predict` method in my web app just like normal lib call? If I call `predict(testData: RDD[Vector]): RDD[Double]`, my program has to be in driver program? So in the 'real-time' prediction, 1st approach could be better, cause I don't have to trigger a job for each client request in 2nd approach?

Comment: @Stephen  Your first scenario is incorrect.  The Spark job needs to be launched via either `spark-submit` or `spark-shell` - that is unless you use a `local` master.  Spark does not give you *real time*: the best you can likely achieve is hundreds of milliseconds - and even that is tricky.

Comment: I think I did not describe my question well. Say if I have a job for model training, and I 'spark-submit' to cluster, after hours of computing, I get the model, saved in HDFS or local storage. Ok, now I have the model, I want to integrate the model in my web application for prediction, and I hope the page response is fast enough, here I call it real-time. My question is: how to do that? Could I load the persistent model file in to my web application, and I simply treat 'spark-assembly-xxx.jar' as a normal lib, so I can load the model in my web app controller, then do the prediction?

Comment: Continue my question above, if I can not directly integrate the model into my web application, how to let the web app do the prediction with the trained model?

Comment: @Stephen  Spark models are primarily distributed. If you want to run something locally / small data/size footprint then you might be looking for something like a `numpy/scikit` (python)  or an `R` model.  Spark does support export to `pmml` for *some* ML algorithms. You will need to use the "old school"  mllib version to get the save to pmml  feature: look at `o.a.s.mllib.classification.LogisticRegression` : it supports `with PMMLExportable`